# Push() is not working in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am newbie in Reactjs. I am making a form in which form data will store in an array and shows on same page after submission. I am using push() to store data in array but when I press submit button then error encountered:

> Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

I am unable to store data in array. and Here is my code snippet:

```
import React from "react";
data = [{ firstName :'', lastName:'', username:'' }];

export default class Form extends React.Component {

  state = {
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    username: ""
  }

  change = e => {
    this.props.onChange({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state);

    let firstName = this.state.firstName.value;
    let lastName = this.state.lastName.value;
    let username = this.state.username.value; 


    this.setState({
      data :  this.state.data.push({firstName, lastName, username})
    })


  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        //Form Fields
     )
    }
```

I want help regarding this. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Firstly, set the initial state in the constructor. Secondly, NEVER mutate the state. `push()` mutates the array you call it on. Make a copy of the state array then mutate that. Thirdly, in your `setState()` call, you're setting `data` equal to the _return_ value of the push call, which is the array's new length, not the new array itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its better when you use `setState` like there:

```
import React from "react";
    data = [{ firstName :'', lastName:'', username:'' }];

    export default class Form extends React.Component {

      state = {
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
        username: "",
        data
      }

      change = e => {
        this.props.onChange({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
        this.setState({
          [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        });
      };

      onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state);

        let firstName = this.state.firstName.value;
        let lastName = this.state.lastName.value;
        let username = this.state.username.value; 

        /**
         * change here!!
         */
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            data: [...prevState.data,{ firstName, lastName, username }]
         }))
       }

      render() {
        return (
          <form>
            //Form Fields
         )
        }
```

more info:
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/functional-setstate-is-the-future-of-react-374f30401b6b

Comment: I got this error after changing this:  Cannot convert undefined or null to object at this line: data: [...prevState.data,{ firstName, lastName, username }]

Comment: @VishalDonga yep, its not initialized state with default `data`. see edited answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise the data as an array in state.

```
state = {
  data = []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just took a cursory look, I think you should move some code around. Your data definition should be moved to the class and you can quiet possibly use it to initialize your state. As others have suggested, you state initialization should be in the constructor.
Try this:

```
    import React from "react";


    export default class Form extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      state = {
       data : [{ firstName :'', lastName:'', username:'' }]
      }
    }

      change = e => {
        this.props.onChange({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
        this.setState({
          [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        });
      };

      onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state);

        let firstName = this.state.firstName.value;
        let lastName = this.state.lastName.value;
        let username = this.state.username.value; 


        this.setState({
          data :  this.state.data.push({firstName, lastName, username})
        })


      render() {
        return (
          <form>
            //Form Fields
         )
        }
```

Comment: Stored data in 1st index of array but failed while 2nd form submission and got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Inside setState you can not use push() method. So instead of pushing inside setState 
just first push outside and then set it inside setState

data.push({firstName,lastName,username});
    this.setState({
      data:data,
    })

Comment: Actually you are right about push() method but it also works in setState. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - and this is super important - **never modify `state` directly!** Check out [this link](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly) of the documentation.

Next the reason you are getting your error, is because `state` does not know about your `data` array.

If you want to do stuff correctly, you should use [an updater function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253351/correct-modification-of-state-arrays-in-reactjs) to modify your state.

Answer (score 0):

try with

`this.setState({ data: [...this.state.data, {firstName, lastName, username}] });`

Comment: I am unable to understand the concept of ... after reading the documentation too. What it actually do?

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer after applying this solution in onSubmit() function:

```
 onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state);

     data =
     {
        firstName : this.state.firstName,
        lastName : this.state.lastName,
        username : this.state.username, 
        email : this.state.email,
        password : this.state.password,
        birthDay : this.state.birthDay,
        birthMonth : this.state.birthMonth,
        birthYear : this.state.birthYear,
        gender : this.state.gender
    }
     this.state.data.push(data)
     this.setState(this.state);



   };
```